# Intuition behind odds of winning 0 times approaching 1/e

Tags: statistics

I am learning about the number $e$. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) page says that in a Bernoulli experiment the odds of never winning in $n$ trials approach $1/e$ as $n$ tends to infinity.  I am trying to develop an intuition about why that might be. What's going on?

Comment: Note that $1/e$ is the probability (as $n\to\infty$) of never winning $n$ trials *if each trial has probability $1/n$*.

Comment: We only can answer your question if you tell us what your intuition about $e$ is.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I don't think that would be needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would help to take some formal demonstration of this fact and elaborate it in more concrete terms.  For example:

Start with the formal facts that
$$ \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n \to e^x
\quad\text{and in particular,}\quad
\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n \to e $$
These limits are often interpreted in terms of "continuously compounded interest".  If you lend somebody a dollar at a 100% annual interest rate, then at the end of the year they owe you 2 dollars; if the interest is compounded every half year, then it's 50% after six months, so they owe $\frac32$ dollars, and then another 50% on top of that at the end of the year, so they owe $\frac32\cdot\frac32 = \frac94$ dollars; if the interest is compounded three times, it's $(1+\frac13)^3$ owed at the end of the year; and so on.  If interest is compounded continuously, they owe you $e$ dollars at the end of the year.

It's a similar story if you're taking a loss: a 100% loss over a year turns 1 dollar into 0 dollars; a 50% loss twice turns 1 dollar into $\frac12$, then into $\frac14$ dollars; a 33% loss three times turns 1 dollar into $(1-\frac13)^3$ dollars; a continuously compounded loss turns 1 dollar into $\frac1e$ dollars.

Now, we can re-cast these gain/loss processes in probabilistic terms instead.  Rather than saying something like "in six months you lose 50% of your dollar", we could say "each cent has a 50% chance of being lost in six months, so the *expected* loss in six months is 50%".  Increasing the frequency of compounding, we then move to a scenario where "each cent has a 33% chance of being lost in $\frac13$ of a year", and so on; just as, in the continuously compounding loss scenario, 1 dollar becomes $\frac1e$ dollars, in the continuously compounding probabilistic scenario, each cent ends up with a probability $\frac1e$ of surviving the year.

(If you don't care for the financial metaphor, you could try translating all this into other terms.  Newton's law of temperature, for example, also involves this kind of exponential decay, and you could think of it as arising from small units of heat having some probability of moving from one object to another.  Or maybe you'd prefer to think of radioactive decay.  Or population growth/decay.)

Answer (score 1):

My intiution tells me that trying $1,000,000$ times something with a probability of $1/1,000,000$ is not very different if we change each million by a billion, for example, so there must be *some* limit.

The precise value $1/e$ is very far from my intuition.

Answer (score 0):

In a Bernoulli trial with win probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and losing probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$, the probability that you will lose $n$ consecutive trials equals $ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$.

Since $$e \equiv \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n,$$
we have that $$ \frac{1}{e} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n. $$
As $n\to\infty$, it follows that $$\frac{1}{e}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n=\mathbb{P}(\text{$n$ consecutive losses}),$$
which shows the intuition.